# Export Cucumber reports as a zip file in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to export our cucumber reports as a zip file that includes the reports in HTML formats and contains all the necessary files and screenshots after successful execution of our pipeline. What configuration should be added in the yaml file so that it can be possible?

Thanks